# Add a variable to a data posted with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code which is working correctly.I need to assign a variable to the data returned from the php code.Please help me solve this problem because it is really disturbing me

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#nickname').keyup(function(){
                $('#checkUser').show();
                var nickname=$(this).val();
                if(nickname !=''){
                    $.post('php/checkUser.php',{nickname:nickname},function(data){
//for example var value=$(this).val(data);
                        if(data=='false'){
                            $('#checkUser').html('<img src="images/true.png" &nbsp width=15>');
                            $('#nickname').css('width','382');
                        } else if(data=='true'){
                            $('#checkUser').html('<img src="images/false.png" &nbsp width=15>');
                            $('#nickname').css('width','382');
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $('#nickname').css('width','400');
                    $('#checkUser').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: what do you see if you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Its telling me undefined.How can i write it as a variable?

Comment: did you put `console.log` just before `if(data=='false')`?

Comment: Yaah Ali but still not working...please will you mind if i ask an assistance from you? i hosted my website one month ago.It is really functioning well on my localhost but after hosting it,the if else statement inside the post function is not working.What might be the problem

Comment: can you link me to the url, where this code is running??

Comment: https://www.culdesign.com/SignUp.php .. On typing the user text box ,i need to echo an image if the user exist or vice versa

Comment: javascript has errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` may be because you are debugging...

Comment: Yah i am still debugging it let me change the code to its initial

Comment: I have changed the code check it now please Ali.

Comment: Thanks in advance.Please help me solve the issue even if it means to give you something you solve it for me because has realy eaten my nerves the past one month

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your live code and debugged it, Found this issue:

Your php script is returning `"  false"` instead of `"false"`
that's why `if(data=='false')` is not working

if you add your `checkUser.php` code I can help you further...

Comment: <?php
require'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['nickname'])){
$username=$_POST['nickname'];
 
 $query="select `account_id` from `user_account` where `user_name`='$username'";
 if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
 $row=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
 if($row==1){
 echo'true';
 }else if($row==0){
 echo'false';
 }
 }else{
 echo mysql_error();
 }
}
?>

Comment: Please attach checkuser.php and connection.php...  so I can see from where these extra spaces are coming... (you can remove your db details from connection.php)

Comment: This is for connection

Comment: Hae Ali i have attached the copy you have requested

Comment: <?php $link = mysql_connect('', '', ''); if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } mysql_select_db(tec_account); ?>

Comment: Hi Ali how can i test for this because i have seen the error you quoted and it is occuring severally on my website

Comment: I want you to attach these files for me... not copy paste the code... upload files somewhere and give link... thanks

Comment: Will you mind if you give me your email i sent them to you ... my email is xtech008@gmail.com